# unit testing @Suspended AsyncResponse controller

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jersey, dropwizard

I am upgrading to be fully asynchronous and I have an exsiting test that unit tests the controller with mocked dependencies and tests the various paths. I can't figure out how to convert this unit test. I am using dropwizard/jersey and the method I want to test looks like this now

```
 @POST
public void getPostExample(final Map body, @Suspended final AsyncResponse
 asyncResponse){}
```

The old test uses mockito/junit and uses `@InjectMocks` for the controller which it then calls the method on `getPostExample` and asserts some info on the response. The services it calls are mocked but I can't find much when I search for how to manually get this to return data.  I can get access to the AsyncResponse but in the real code that calls the resume with results. Should I be calling resume in my test?

Comment: A lot of what I have found is creating a client to execute the request but I don't really want to spin up everything and test actual HTTP call unless I have to and perhaps can change this to integration test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*"Should I be calling resume in my test"*. No. What you should do is test that the `resume` method is called with the expected arguments. This is how you test the *behavior* of the method.

What you can do is use Mockito's [ArgumentCaptor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture the `Response` that is passed to the `resume` method, and then make your assertions on that `Response`. You will need to mock the `AsyncResponse` for this to work. Below is an example

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AsyncMockTest {

    @Mock
    private AsyncResponse response;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Response> captor;

    @Test
    public void testAsyncResponse() {
        final TestResource resource = new TestResource();
        resource.get(this.response);

        Mockito.verify(this.response).resume(this.captor.capture());
        final Response res = this.captor.getValue();

        assertThat(res.getEntity()).isEqualTo("Testing");
        assertThat(res.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);
    }

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @GET
        @ManagedAsync
        public void get(@Suspended AsyncResponse response) {
            response.resume(Response.ok("Testing").build());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before doing assertion, you may want to wait for the desired timeout, otherwise assert statement will fail

Comment: @webjockey This is a _unit test_ (not integration test) with a mock AsyncResponse. No need to wait for anything.

Comment: @peeskillet i seem to get "there were zero interactions with this mock" error . Any suggestions

Comment: If you're return the response on a new thread, that's going to happen. If you want to forget about managing your own threads, you can just annotate the method with `@MangagedAsync` and Jersey will manage the threads for you internally. If you do this, then your code would look just like mine above, then the test would work. If you are managing your own threads, then you need to consider the fact that the interaction is not synchronous and fix the test accordingly. Maybe with some countdown latches. Can't tell without seeing some code.

Comment: @peeskillet ok i still don see how the response is returned . I am currenly applying Thread.sleep in my test to get the response . I am using ManagedAsync btw .

Comment: @BalajiV the response is returned by calling resume. If all your code in the method is synchronus, there is no reason for this test to fail. Use my exact code to test, then compare it against yours

Comment: Thanks for neat answer. I made another mistake of declaring `captor.capture()` first and then invoking `resource.get(response)`, which also resulted in "zero interactions with this mock" error. Fixing the sequence, fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add mockito `after()` method call to wait for the other thread to finish; that should resolve issue with exception, f.e.:
`Mockito.verify(response, after(10000)).resume(this.captor.capture());`